# Does understimulation of the brain have negative consequences?

Tags: brain

Ive been looking for the correct scientific term for understimulation of the brain i.e. lack of a varied experience of activities and its effect on people.

I havent been able to find any studies though because theres probably a term for this that Im missing, so I was wondering if anyone knows a more scientific term or any studies

Comment: I think this is a bit poorly defined/too broad; what is a "negative consequence"? What exactly does it mean for the brain to be "understimulated"? There are certainly examples in e.g. the rodent literature that research animals kept in austere environments behave differently than research animals kept in more elaborate ones. There are also studies on reduced quality of life and morbidity/mortality for older adults who live alone, but it doesn't necessarily seem appropriate to describe these as "understimulation of the brain".

Comment: There are also trivial examples from development, e.g., if you don't "stimulate a brain" with books and other things to read, a person won't develop the ability to read. That's a specific issue with particular social relevance, but you could substitute just about anything in there with respect to "understimulation" and an associated consequence. If you don't ever throw a ball, you won't be able to throw a ball; if you don't ever learn to drive, you won't be able to drive, etc.